# redundant requirement of dense Zariski open set for rational map

Tags: algebraic-geometry, definition, rational-functions

This is the definition of rational map in Harris, AG: a first course.

Def 7.3: $X$ is irreducible variety and $Y$ any variety. $\phi:X\to Y$ is rational if $\phi$ is defined on a dense open set $U$ with the equivalence relation that two functions agrees upon the intersection of their corresponding dense open set(i.e. $\phi_1,U_1$ and $\phi_2,U_2$ agrees on $\phi_1|_{U_1\cap U_2}=\phi_2|_{U_1\cap U_1}$ and this equivalence class defines $\phi$).

I do not see the requirement of dense is necessary. If $X$ is irreducible, then $X=(X-U)\cup\bar{U}$. So $\bar{U}=X$ which is automatic.

Comment: One just has to exclude the empty set $U$.

Comment: @HagenKnaf, So the dense set is required to exclude the empty set?

Comment: Yes. I guess Harris just copied the definition from another source, where rational maps are defined for more general schemes.